# removing punctuation of strings effectively

Tags: string, julia

I read in a text and want to remove all the punctuation of it. My first idea was:

```
data = readlines("text.txt")
data = lowercase.(data)
data = replace.(data, [','], [""])
data = replace.(data, ['.'], [""])
data = replace.(data, ['?'], [""])
data = replace.(data, [';'], [""])
data = replace.(data, ['!'], [""])
data = replace.(data, [':'], [""])
data = replace.(data, ['('], [""])
data = replace.(data, [')'], [""])
```

This gets quite fast annoying. I did not find a way to combine them all in one statement. With `replace.(data, [".", ";"], ["", ""])` I get a DimensionMismatch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a loop of course.

Comment: (sorry I don't know [tag:julia-lang] so I can't help, but it should be applicable to all languages with a loop, use a fold may also work if your language have this)

Comment: (by "effectively" you meant "without repeating code", right?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When broadcasting if you do not want a collection (like an array or a tuple) to be iterated over you should wrap it in an array (in the example I use only two characters `,` and `;` as substitution, but this can be more):

```
julia> data = ["a,b;c","x,y;z"]
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "a,b;c"
 "x,y;z"

julia> replace.(data, [[',',';']], "")
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "abc"
 "xyz"
```

The key part is `[[',',';']]` which wraps an array of substitution alternatives into a one element array.

Another approach would be to use a regular expression:

```
julia> replace.(data, r"[,;]", "")
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "abc"
 "xyz"
```

Now the substitution pattern `r"[,;]"` does not need to be wrapped.

If you care about the performance the first pattern with `[[',',';']]` is a bit faster, but using regular expression is more flexible as it allows you to capture more complex patterns.

## EDIT

Now it would be:

```
julia> replace.(data, [',',';'] => "")
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "abc"
 "xyz"
```

or

```
julia> replace.(data, r"[,;]" => "")
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "abc"
 "xyz"
```

Comment: `filter.(c->iszero(search(";,",c)),data)` benchmarks faster

Comment: An excellent solution! For the future: in Julia 0.7 `search` should be replaced by `findfirst` and then `iszero` by a test of `nothing` returned.

Comment: As of now, it should be `replace.(data, r"[,;]" => "")` .

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you should just be able to use a regex:

```
data = readlines("text.txt")
data = lowercase.(data)
data = replace.(data, [r"""[,.:;?!()]"""], [""])
```

I haven't tried it because the Julia on my machine is not recent enough to support broadcast function calls.

Comment: Thanks. You just have to use only one " `r"..."`

Comment: @hamlet ...until you decide that `"` is also punctuation that should be removed.

Comment: @rici That is correct, but I would say that escaping the single `"` is shorter and easier to read. For example, `"[,\""` versus `"""[,""""`.

Comment: @rikh: I don't believe `"""[,""""` would work in any version of Julia. When I wrote that comment, the Julia version I was using would have allowed `"""[,"""""` but, somewhat mysteriously, it meant the same as `"""[,"""` (being a string juxtaposed to an empty string). But about that time a change was made to Julia so that more recent versions generated a syntax error ("cannot juxtapose string literal"). Anyway, strings like that are very difficult to write legibly, and your style is as good as anyone else's. On the whole, I think C++ got raw strings right.

Comment: You are right. I should have tested it and instead typed `"""[","""` versus `"[,\""` (tested both in Julia 1.4). Thank you for your explanation on the history of the language. (Things change pretty quickly it seems.)

Answer (score 1):

It can be handy to simply let Unicode decide what characters are punctuation:

```
julia> import Unicode: ispunct

julia> filter(!ispunct, "a,b;c")
"abc"
```

This of course also works nicely with broadcasting:

```
julia> filter.(!ispunct, ["a,b;c","x,y;z"])
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "abc"
 "xyz"
```

This same predicate also works nicely with `strip` (to remove leading/trailing punctuation).

Answer (score 0):

I could not make the above solutions work.

Here is something that works, although it is very complicated:

```
join(replace(split("A.B,C", ""), "."=>"", ","=>""))
"ABC"
```